# MySQL Connector/C++ declare variable

Tags: c++, mysql

I want to create a stored procedure with 4 insert and i have this code

```
  Driver * driver = get_driver_instance();
  auto_ptr< Connection > vCon(driver->connect(getHost(), getUser(), getPassword()));
  vCon->setSchema(getDB());
  auto_ptr< Statement > vStmt(vCon->createStatement());

  vStmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add");
  vStmt->execute("CREATE PROCEDURE add() begin DECLARE vEvId int DEFAULT 0; DECLARE vAdrEvId int DEFAULT 0; insert into adrEv(den) values('test'); select last_insert_id() into vAdrEvId; insert into ev(den,adrEvId) values('test',vAdrEvId);  select last_insert_id() into vEvId;  ... other insert ...   END;");

  vStmt->execute("CALL add()");
  vStmt->execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add");
```

whay i get this error `# ERR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'add' at line 1 (MySQL error code: 1064, SQLState: 42000 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ADD` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) for MySQL. Try using a more specific/descriptive procedure name.